# how to remove all Mesh objects from the scene in three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, scene

I am passing the name of the 3d model add and texture name in a function 
and the result is the 3d model is rendered in a scene. 
All what am in stuck is ,I just want to remove only the 3d objects from the scene

when i use scene.children to get the objects it contains the light and camera too
i just want to remove only the Meshes in the scene

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this solves your problem,

```
for (let i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(scene.children[i].type === "Mesh")
        scene.remove(scene.children[i]);
}
```

Note that it is a reverse for loop. This is because we are removing items from the array that we are iterating, and we need to preserve the indices.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing THREE objects from your scene is not enough to delete them from memory. You have to call the dispose() methods on the objects' geometries, materials and textures.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5175

After you call your dispose and remove methods, do a diagnostic like this (where this.renderer is your THREE.Renderer):

```
if (this.renderer && (this.renderer.info.memory.geometries || this.renderer.info.memory.programs || this.renderer.info.memory.textures)) {
    loge("geometries=" + this.renderer.info.memory.geometries + " programs=" + this.renderer.info.memory.programs + " textures=" + this.renderer.info.memory.textures);
}
```

If the number of programs, geometries and textures isn't stable, you are inviting performance issues and a memory leak.